# Logical comparison in ionic view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I try to compare two dynamic values in a ionic view template with angular.

If the value equals to the other value then display the value else keep on looping

```
<ion-list>
// Loop the results 
<ion-item *ngFor="let protocole of protocoles">

    <ng-template[ngIf]="{{value}}=={{other_value}}">
    <div>
        <ion-label>
            <h2>{{ protocole.item}} {{ modal_data_prot_detail_code }}</h2>
        </ion-label> 
    </div>

    // ELSE
    </ng-template>
        <ion-label"><h2>{{ protocole.item}}}</h2> </ion-label>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: What about `*ngIf="value == other_value"`?

Comment: It seems the same thing, it produces multiple errors

Answer (score 0):

You are making some attempt to `if .. else` here it seems. So let's just correct that, and for example you could show it like:

```html
<div *ngIf="protocole.item === other_value; else other">
   <ion-label>
      <h2>{{ protocole.item}} {{ modal_data_prot_detail_code }}</h2>
   </ion-label> 
</div>

<ng-template #other>
   <ion-label">
     <h2>{{ protocole.item}}}</h2> 
   </ion-label>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let protocole of protocoles">
            <ng-container 
                 [ngTemplateOutlet]="value == other_value" ? firstTemplate: secondTemplate" 
                 [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{protocole:protocole}">
            </ng-container>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ng-template #firstTemplate let-protocole='protocole'>
        <div>
            <ion-label>
                <h2>{{ protocole.item}} {{ modal_data_prot_detail_code }}</h2>
            </ion-label> 
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #secondTemplate let-protocole='protocole'>
        <ion-label"><h2>{{ protocole.item}}}</h2> </ion-label>
    </ng-template>
```